# Maxwell and special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations

The derivation of the speed of light from Maxwell's equations yields an expression which does not contain a term for the velocity of the frame of reference in which the derivation is performed. Is this simply an inconsequential effect of the manner in which Maxwell's equations were formulated, or does it instead demonstrate that the speed of light is frame-independent? I ask this question because I recall from one of the physics books (which I since gave away) in my collection, the author made the point that Maxwell himself could have used that result to demonstrate special relativity before Einstein. Is that assertion correct?

Comment: The velocity of the frame of reference *relative to what*?

Comment: Yes, it's because Maxwell's equations are Lorentz covariant.

Comment: Excellent, @JohnRennie-  Care to write that up as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: True, maxwell himself could have given special relativity, but on reading this essay(https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/dyson.pdf) by Dyson, we can understand Maxwell was not happy about his own theory, rather he was searching ways to explain his equations using mechanistic formulation which was at that time popular and long held belief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The derivation of the speed of light from Maxwell's equations yields an expression which does not contain a term for the velocity of the frame of reference in which the derivation is performed

It really does - if you follow classical derivation based on Galileo relativity transformations. Maxwell equations are not invariant under these transformations, which were at the time most natural to use.

Back then it was natural to think that classical formulation of Maxwell equations hold only for one special frame of reference and the job of physicist was to find it. The thought was, that this frame of reference was locked to some substance called eather in analogy to sound waves and air.

It was only after every attempt to actually find such reference frame failed and after Lorentz demonstrated that if you use Maxwell equations also on your clocks and lengths the  absolute lengths and times become immaterial. The theory was still formulated with reference to these absolute coordinates, but it became obvious that all the clocks and meter sticks will deform in just the way that makes finding this absolute reference frame impossible.

Only then it became natural to get rid of it and redefine simultaneity using Maxwell theory and thus reach special theory of relativity.

So in principle, Maxwell could do it since his equations are invariant under Lorentz transformations, but to make this transformations central to whole of physics just because of that seems too crazy of an idea.

Answer (score -2):

Maxwell's 19th century theory posited that the speed of light does vary with the speed of the observer:

John Norton: "That [Maxwell] theory allows light to slow and be frozen in the frame of reference of a sufficiently rapidly moving observer."  http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/Chasing.pdf